# non swapable pages in memory ? why?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I wonder : 
Why would one want to set a page to be non-swapable ?

There are, of course, performance issues, but other than that, is there a reason for a non-swapable page ?

Comment: Say, for example, you have memory that needs to be DMAed somewhere.

Comment: Also, that makes it less likely that sensitive data is stored to disk. Beware of hibernation, emulation and core-dumps though.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're looking for reasons the kernel might need to, or reasons an application might want to request that the kernel make pages non-swappable?

Comment: Also, some hard realtime software can't afford random parts of it to be blocked by pagefault+swapping some page back to memory from disk.

Comment: BTW: for the kernel itself, setting pages containing pagetables to not swappable will prevent double-faulting.

Comment: Deduplicator , can you explain more the security issue you suggested ?
Why is the main memory more safe than disk ?

Comment: @wildplasser it is not possible to set kernel pages to non-swappable.   everything to be accessed in kernel mode has to be available and accessible.   In linux, swapping out pages is always referring to userspace memory pages.   http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10678

Answer (score 4):

The [man page for mlock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) mentions two main uses:

- when the application must be reactive, such as real time systems or watchdogs
- when the data are sensitive (e.g. password) and you'd rather not have them copied to persistent storage beyond the control of your application.

Comment: +1 for linking to man7.org rather than the typical spammy and outdated manpage sites.

Comment: R.., it can be better to link kernel.org: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlockall.2.html and opengroup.org...